# mysql - sum of json elements, group by and select all

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

I have the following table structure and data:

| DumpTime | ProcId | NodeId | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-07 13:03:03 | 9 | NODE_IDD02 | {"First":1,"Second":5,"Third":2} |
| 2022-07-07 13:17:35 | 8 | NODE_IDD03 | {"First":2,"Second":3,"Third":4} |
| 2022-07-07 13:22:35 | 9 | NODE_IDD02 | {"First":0,"Second":3,"Third":0} |
| 2022-07-07 13:03:03 | 0 | NODE_IDD01 | {"First":0,"Second":0,"Third":5} |
| 2022-07-07 13:17:35 | 8 | NODE_IDD03 | {"First":4,"Second":1,"Third":1} |
| 2022-07-07 13:22:35 | 0 | NODE_IDD01 | {"First":3,"Second":3,"Third":3} |

I have to group the rows using ProcId and NodeId and add the respective values of the JSON elements in Stats (The DumpTime has no significance).

The output should be:

| DumpTime | ProcId | NodeId | Stats |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-07-07 13:03:03 | 9 | NODE_IDD02 | {"First":1,"Second":8,"Third":2} |
| 2022-07-07 13:17:35 | 8 | NODE_IDD03 | {"First":6,"Second":4,"Third":5} |
| 2022-07-07 13:03:03 | 0 | NODE_IDD01 | {"First":3,"Second":3,"Third":8} |

I am able to get the sum of respective json elements but it is the total sum and not grouped. I used `sum(json_extract())` for it.

Also, output has to be in the specified form so that it can be unmarshaled into a struct.
What should be the sql query to achieve the same?

Answer (score 1):

To get what you need you can use a query like this

```
SELECT 
    MIN(data.dump_time) AS DumpTime,
    data.proc_id AS ProcId,
    data.node_id AS NodeId,
    JSON_OBJECTAGG(q.attr, q.attr_total) AS Stats
FROM (
    SELECT 
        proc_id,
        attr,
        CAST(SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(stats, CONCAT('$.', attr))) AS SIGNED) AS attr_total 
    FROM  data
    CROSS JOIN JSON_TABLE(CAST(JSON_KEYS(stats) AS JSON), '$[*]' COLUMNS(attr VARCHAR(20) PATH '$')) t
    GROUP BY proc_id, attr
) q
JOIN data ON q.proc_id = data.proc_id
GROUP BY data.proc_id, data.node_id
```

You can check a working demo [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=52bc922c22777ac7f00f443844e09f61)

---

If all `stats` values have the same attributes ("First", "Second", "Third") then you can make it a little simplier like this

```
SELECT 
    MIN(data.dump_time) AS DumpTime,
    data.proc_id AS ProcId,
    data.node_id AS NodeId,
    JSON_OBJECTAGG(q.attr, q.attr_total) AS Stats
FROM (
    SELECT 
        proc_id,
        attr,
        CAST(SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(stats, CONCAT('$.', attr))) AS SIGNED)  AS attr_total 
    FROM  data
    CROSS JOIN (VALUES ROW("First"), ROW("Second"), ROW("Third")) t(attr)
    GROUP BY proc_id, attr
) q
JOIN data ON q.proc_id = data.proc_id
GROUP BY data.proc_id, data.node_id
```

You can check it [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dde5fa758180ded8f113d4797e659da9)

Comment: Will this query be same in case of mariadb?