# MySQL: best way to sum all JSON values in each cell with varying number of keys and nulls

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-json

Let there be a table **data** with two columns

| id | parts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | {"1": 1, "2": 0, "3": 2, "4": 0, "5": 0} |
| 2 | NULL |
| 3 | {"6": 1, "7": 0} |
| 4 | {"3": 1} |
| 5 | null |

Column `id` is integer type and column `parts` can have JSON expressions, empty cells (NULL) as well as JSON nulls.

The question is fairly simple: how does one find the sum of all values in each cell in `parts`, leaving only not null cells. The final result should be:

| id | sum_parts |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 3 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |

Answer (score 1):

I managed to get a solution using Alexey's answer from this question [mysql - sum of json elements, group by and select all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73250552/mysql-sum-of-json-elements-group-by-and-select-all), but I find it a little clunky:

```
with data_not_null as
(
SELECT * FROM data
WHERE data.parts IS NOT NULL
    AND data.parts != CAST('null' AS JSON)
)

SELECT id, SUM(JSON_EXTRACT(CONCAT('$."', key, '"'))) sum_parts
FROM data_not_null,
    JSON_TABLE(CAST(JSON_KEYS(parts->'$.') AS JSON), '$[*]' COLUMNS(key VARCHAR(2) PATH '$') t
GROUP BY id
```

Comment: Every use of JSON in MySQL is at least a little bit clunky. Use normal rows and columns if you want it to be elegant.

Comment: @BillKarwin yes, but unfortunately I did not design the database that I am using. So I have to work with what I've got :)

Comment: Then you must accept that it will be clunky.